# MiKTex crashed on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: miktex, ubuntu

I have installed MiKTex on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. In the meantime, I use TexStudio as editor. In the beginning everything went fine, but for some reason, now, MiKTex does not answer anymore, and I cannot compile my document on TexStudio. When I want to open MiKTex the following message appears:

[image]

I tried to uninstall MikTex and I install it again following what is given on the MiKTex website (https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx) but nothing changes... Always the same error appears! Anybody as an idea about what's going on and what should be done to solve the issue?

Thank you in advance for any kind help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Delete file 0997c***** .fndb-5 and run command pdflatex with some file.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:
$ sudo rm -rf ~/.miktex
then in MiKTex console select: Settings and then select:
Always install missing packages on-the-fly.